# Error 70 Permission Denied when attempting to Backup Database Backend

Tags: vba, ms-access, backup

I am trying to automatically back up the backend of my split database which is located on a network drive. Unfortunately, I keep getting the error displayed in the title.

**Code:**

```vb
Function BackUpBE()

On Error GoTo Err_backup

Dim strNewBEname As String
Dim strOldBEname As String
Dim strDateStamp As String


strOldBEname = "P:\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\Durament_db_be.accdb"
'strOldBEname = "\\192.XXX.XX.XXX\Daten\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\Durament_db_be.accdb"

strDateStamp = Format(Date, "d.m.yy")

strNewBEname = "P:\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\BackUp\" & "Backup_vom_" & strDateStamp & ".accdb"
'strNewBEname = "\\192.XXX.XX.XXX\Daten\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\BackUp\" & "Backup_vom_" & strDateStamp & ".accdb"

'copy database
FileCopy strOldBEname, strNewBEname

MsgBox "The back-end database has been backed up!"

Exit_Backup:
Exit Function

Err_backup:
MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description

Resume Exit_Backup
End Function
```

The code simply copies the current backend into another folder. At first I thought it was a server related issue concerning a password that is required. So I mapped the drive and used a local path, however, it still does not work. I have already stepped through the code using f8 and the error occurs upon exiting out of the function which does not make much sense to me. I appreciate any hints that would allow me to find the faulty part within my code, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you manually copy and paste the file to new location? There may folder write permission issue?

Comment: You should put an statement `Exit Function` before your label `Err_backup:` to prevent that the MsgBox is displayed in any case. But that doesn't explain the Error 70

Comment: @Harun24HR yes I can manually copy and paste to a new location on the server so I do not believe that permissions should be an issue.

Comment: @FunThomas Correct, I forgot to paste that part into my question.

Comment: How is the code triggered?

Comment: I created a macro which essentially is only one line with the command `RunCode` which calls my function upon startup of access because I called the macro `AutoExec`.

Comment: Does it work if **nobody** uses the database (there is no backend .laccdb), and you run this code from a separate database (not the frontend with the linked tables)?

Comment: @Andre when running the code from an empty database it works.

Comment: @Andre do you believe that the locking file blocks me from copying? and if so would you know a way around that?

Comment: The .laccdb file doesn't block you, it only indicates that the .accdb file is in use. Can you copy the BE .accdb in Explorer, while it is in use?

Comment: Yes interestingly that works as well.

Comment: Then you might have luck trying different methods to copy the file, e.g. FileSystemObject or Shell commands.

Comment: Thanks, @Andre that did the trick. I'll happily accept this as an answer if you want to type it up.

Comment: Cool. :) I think it would be more useful if you wrote an answer yourself, showing how you did it - I could only guess what the actually working method would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andre suggested I managed to use FileSystemObject to copy the backend while the frontend is in use.

```vb
Function BackUpBE()

On Error GoTo Err_backup

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strNewBEname As String
Dim strOldBEname As String
Dim strDateStamp As String

strOldBEname = "P:\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\Durament_db_be.accdb"
'strOldBEname = "\\192.XXX.XX.XXX\Daten\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\Durament_db_be.accdb"

strDateStamp = Format(Date, "d.m.yy")

strNewBEname = "P:\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\BackUp\" & "Backup_vom_" & strDateStamp & ".accdb"
'strNewBEname = "\\192.XXX.XX.XXX\Daten\Access Datenbank\Durament_db_be\BackUp\" & "Backup_vom_" & strDateStamp & ".accdb"

'copy current BE to Folder

Call fso.CopyFile(strOldBEname, strNewBEname)

MsgBox "The back-end database has been backed up!"

Exit_Backup:
Exit Function

Err_backup:
MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description

Resume Exit_Backup

End Function
```